# Magento Exception:Wrong product type to extract configurable options

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, customer-account, option, quoteitem

I have a custom module for viewing products in cart at the My account Dashboard. It's working fine, but some times it throws exceptional error at the `getItemOptions()` function.

Customer/Block/Cart.php

```
class Mage_Customer_Block_Cart extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{
    public function _construct(){
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('customer/cart/cart.phtml');
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getLayout()->getBlock('root')
            ->setHeaderTitle(Mage::helper('customer')->__('mycart'));
    }

    public function getAllItems(){
        $items = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        //$items = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getAllVisibleItems();
        return $items;
    }

    public function getSubTotal()
    {
        $subTotal = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
        return $subTotal;
    }

    public function getTotal(){
        $grandTotal = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
        return $grandTotal;
    }

    public function getCartUrl(){
        return Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart', array('_secure'=>true));
    }

    public function getCheckoutUrl(){
        return Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage', array('_secure'=>true));
    }

    public function getItemOptions($item)
    {
        /* @var $helper Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Configuration */
        $helper = Mage::helper('catalog/product_configuration');
        $options = $helper->getConfigurableOptions($item);
        return $options;

    }

    public function getFormatedOptionValue($optionValue)
    {
        /* @var $helper Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Configuration */
        $helper = Mage::helper('catalog/product_configuration');
        $params = array(
            'max_length' => 55,
            'cut_replacer' => ' <a href="#" class="dots" onclick="return false">...</a>'
        );
        return $helper->getFormattedOptionValue($optionValue, $params);
    }

}
```

cart.phtml:

```
<div class="dashboard">
    <div class="page-title">
        <h1><?php echo $this->__('My Cart') ?></h1>
    </div>
    <?php $items = $this->getAllItems();?>

    <form>
        <fieldset>
        <table class="data-table" id="customcarttable">
        <thead>
            <tr class="first last">
                <td>Product</td>
                <td>Size</td>
                <td>Quantity</td>
                <td>Price</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($items as $_item) { ?>
            <?php $_options = $this->getItemOptions($_item); ?>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <?php $productModel =Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); $_prod = $productModel->loadByAttribute('sku', $_item->getSku());?>
                        <a class="product-image" href="#" title="<?php echo $_item->getName();?>">
                        <img class="productimage" src="<?php echo $_prod->getImageUrl();?>" width='113' height='113' alt="<?php echo $_item->getName();?>"/>

                        </a>
                        </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php if ($_options = $this->getItemOptions($_item)):?>
                            <dl class="item-options">
                            <dd>
                                <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
                                <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $this->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>
                                <?php if($_option['label'] == 'Country'){?>
                                    <?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['value']; ?>
                                <?php }elseif($_option['label'] == 'Size'){?>
                                        <?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['value'] ?>
                                <?php }?>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </dd>
                            </dl>
                            <?php endif;?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <h3><?php echo $_item->getQty();?></h3>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="price-box">
                            <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-117">
                                <span class="price"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice($_item->getPrice(), false);?></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php }?>
            <tr><td colspan="3">SubTotal</td>
            <td>
                <div class="price-box">
                    <span class="regular-price">
                        <span class="price"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice($this->getSubTotal(), false);?></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan="3">Total</td>
            <td>
                <div class="price-box">
                    <span class="regular-price">
                        <span class="price"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice($this->getTotal(), false);?></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="buttons-set buttons-set2 cart">
           <a href="<?php echo $this->getCartUrl();?>" title="View Cart" class="view-cart">View Cart</a>
           <a href="<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl();?>" title="Checkout" class="view-cart">Checkout</a>
        </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Exceptional Error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:51:"Wrong product type to extract configurable options.";i:1;s:3609:"#0 /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/Configuration.php(106): Mage::throwException('Wrong product t...')
#1 app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Block/Cart.php(42): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Configuration->getConfigurableOptions(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item))
#2 app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/cart/cart.phtml(39): Mage_Customer_Block_Cart->getItemOptions(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item))
#3 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/html/o...')
#4 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#5 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#6 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#7 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#8 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(577): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('customer_cart', true)
#9 app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Wrapper.php(52): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('', true, true)
#10 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Wrapper->_toHtml()
#11 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#12 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#13 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#14 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#15 app/design/frontend/alosmile/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(71): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#16 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/html/o...')
#17 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/alosmi...')
#18 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#19 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#20 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#21 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#22 app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/CartController.php(15): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#23 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Customer_CartController->indexAction()
#24 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#25 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#26 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#27 app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#28 index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#29 {main}";s:3:"url";s:15:"/customer/cart/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:9:"english_2";}
```

I can't predict why this error occurs. I hope some will help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you check Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Configuration you will see in getConfigurableOptions method next code:

```
$product = $item->getProduct();
$typeId = $product->getTypeId();
if ($typeId != Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
    Mage::throwException($this->__('Wrong product type to extract configurable options.'));
}
```

You are trying get options for all product types in cart, but should do it only for configurable products. Try set checking product type into template and call get options method only for configurable products.

Comment: Thanks for the reply@Denis Kopylov.. I have clearly understand your explanation. I am using configurable products, but sometimes it throws me an exceptional error.